# Как добавить новую вкладку при клике на кнопку?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Button_one') #создаю кнопки 
item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Button_two')

markup.add(item1,item2)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def button_reactions(message):
  if message.chat.type == 'private':
    if message.text == 'Button_two':
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку открывается меню с другими кнопками, а не добавлялись к остальным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def some(message):
    start_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    start_service = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Службы', callback_data='service')
    start_keyboard.add(start_service)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Мiлостi просiмъ', reply_markup=start_keyboard)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'service':
        service_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        service_comproxy_k = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Comproxy', callback_data='comproxy')
        service_keyboard.add(service_comproxy_k)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Выберите:', reply_markup=service_keyboard)
```

используйте inline кнопки, тогда вы сможете их заменять (edit_message_text) + они будут в чате, а не под полем ввода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]